# print all repeated items in array object using java

Tags: java, set, hashset

I would like to know how to print all repeated items in an array of objects. For ex:

```
[
   {
      "key": "KEY1",
      "value": "123",
    },
    {
      "key": "KEY2",
      "value": "234",
    },
    {
       "key": "KEY1",
       "value": "456"
    }
]
```

code: I have this logic but it will exclude the first occurrence of KEY1 and prints only a duplicate of it.

```
Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet();
..for(i in items)..{
  if (duplicates.contains(i.val())) {
     System.out.println('duplicates found');
  }
}
```

I want to print both items as below:

duplicate items found, [KEY1] with values ["123", "456"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that for what you're trying to achieve a `Map<String, List<String>>` would be better suited rather than a `HashSet<String>`. In fact, a `Set` would only tell you whether a key is already contained in the `Set` or not, but it won't keep track of how many values a particular key is bound to.

Here is an implementation where the key's object is used as the key for the `Map` and its value added to the `Map`'s list of values:

```
class MyObject {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    //... contrustcor & getters ...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject[] items = new MyObject[]{new MyObject("KEY1", "123"), new MyObject("KEY2", "234"), new MyObject("KEY1", "456")};
        HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (MyObject obj : items) {
            if (!map.containsKey(obj.getKey())) {
                map.put(obj.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(List.of(obj.getValue())));
            } else {
                map.get(obj.getKey()).add(obj.getValue());
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue().size() > 1) {
                System.out.printf("Duplicate items found, %s with values %s%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead, if you need to add the actual object within the data structure, then regardless of using a `HashSet` or a `HashMap`, your class needs to honor the general equals and hashcode contracts by providing a proper definition for the corresponding methods.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

In fact, a `HashSet` uses a `HashMap` under the hood, so in both cases is necessary to override said methods. This is because a `HashMap` is implemented as an array of buckets, where each entry is stored within a bucket based on the key's `hashCode()`. However, different keys may yield same hashcodes, so multiple entries may be listed within a same bucket. At that point, the `HashMap` has to resort to the `equals()` method to find the exact key within a bucket which corresponds to the inputted entry in order to retrieve or replace an element. This is why it is so crucial to provide a proper definition of the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

In your case, a possible implementation could be:

```
class MyObject {
    private String key;
    private String value;

   //... contrustcor & getters ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyObject myObject = (MyObject) o;
        return Objects.equals(key, myObject.key);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(key);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject[] items = new MyObject[]{new MyObject("KEY1", "123"), new MyObject("KEY2", "234"), new MyObject("KEY1", "456")};
        HashMap<MyObject, List<MyObject>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (MyObject obj : items) {
            if (!map.containsKey(obj)) {
                map.put(obj, new ArrayList<>(List.of(obj)));
            } else {
                map.get(obj).add(obj);
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<MyObject, List<MyObject>> e : map.entrySet()) {
            if (e.getValue().size() > 1) {
                System.out.printf("Duplicate items found, %s with values %s%n", e.getKey().getKey(), e.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify collecting data to map using [Map.computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) - `map.computeIfAbsent(obj.getKey(), str -> new ArrayList<>()).add(obj.getValue());` Printing duplicates  probably will be cleaner streaming the entry set, but both of those are minor stuff.

Comment: @Chaosfire great observation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Prepare a `HashMap` of `List` like `HashMap<String,List<String>>`

```
if(!map.contains(key)) {
    map.put(key,new ArrayList<String>());
} 
map.get(key).add(value);
```

In the end, you can iterate HashMap, check if the ArrayList size >1 and print the message with ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static void printAllRepeatedItems(Item[] items) {
    Arrays.stream(items)
        .collect(groupingBy(Item::key, mapping(Item::value, toList())))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
        .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("duplicate items found, %s with values %s%n",
            e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
}
```

And

```
Item[] items = {
    new Item("KEY1", "123"), 
    new Item("KEY2", "234"),
    new Item("KEY1", "456"),
};
printAllRepeatedItems(items);
```

output:

```
duplicate items found, KEY1 with values [123, 456]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in one *statement* using Java 8 streams:

```java
import java.util.List;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

// ...

record Item(String key, String value) { }

List<String> items = List.of(
    new Item("KEY1", "123"),
    new Item("KEY2", "234"),
    new Item("KEY1", "456")
    );

// ...

items
.stream()
.collect(
    groupingBy(Item::key, 
        mapping(Item::value, toList())))   // Map<String, List<String>>
.entrySet()
.stream()
.filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1) // only duplicates
.map(e -> new Object[] {e.getKey(), e.getValue()})
.map("Duplicate items found, %s with values %s"::formatted)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

Alternative, with some helpers:

```java
// same as above

Collector<Item, ?, Map<String, List<String>>> groupValuesByKey = 
    groupingBy(Item::key, mapping(Item::value, toList()));

Predicate<Entry<?, List<String>>> duplicated = 
    e -> e.getValue().size() > 1;

Function<Entry<?, ?>, String> entryToString = 
    e -> "Duplicate items found, %s with value %s".formatted(e.getKey(), e.getValue());

items
.stream()
.collect(groupValuesByKey)  // Map<String, List<String>>
.entrySet()
.stream()
.filter(duplicated)         // only duplicates
.map(entryToString)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```